# cURL fill webform | Cross-Origin Request Blocked | Third party website

Tags: php, curl, request, cross-domain, blocked

I have a script that adds data to a third-party website, only if I export it a Cross-Origin Request Blocked message is returned.

Is this to be circumvented by an extra parameter?

```html
//=============================================================================
// LBR Add
// https://operator.ovocom.nl/ext/extlbroptionform/extentionId/382685
//=============================================================================
$col_1=$_GET['col1'];
$col_2=$_GET['col2'];
$col_3 =$_GET['col3'];

$form['lbroption']=$col_1;
$form['lbroptionprefix']=$col_2;
$form['extId']=$col_2;

$url="https://operator.ovocom.nl/ext/extlbroptionedit";
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $form);
$res =curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);
//print_r($res);
//exit;
//echo "Data Sent Successfully!";
```

Comment: If you are using cURL, then it is not an actual CORS request to begin with. What makes the other party respond with this error - only they can know, so ask them.

Comment: @CBroe is a third party who can not further advise me how this will work. So apparently there is a trick.

Comment: Well maybe it expects an `Origin` header, if it is actually meant to be used from the client-side …